# HostListener keydown only in the open modal window?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use this code to close the modal window. Now it is closed by the close button. But I want to do something that would be closed on the key

But when you click on the button, it gives an error that it can not close the modal window. And I do not understand why. Here is the whole code of the window:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter, HostListener } from "@angular/core";


@Component({
    selector: "modal-window",
    template: require("./modal-window.component.html"),
    styles: [require('./modal-window.component.css')]
})
export class ModalWindowComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() body: string[];
    @Input() title: string;
@Output() closeWindow: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    let x = event.keyCode;
    if (x === 27) {
        this.closeWindow.emit();
        console.log(event);
    }
}

ngOnInit()
{

}

close()
{
    this.closeWindow.emit();
}

}
```

Comment: `it gives an error` Please add this error

Comment: What exactly the error is? Please edit your question and add that error.